# PHP - Extracting ids from a string to run against a function

Tags: php

I was wondering if someone could help me out.

Im extracting a string from my database which is formatted like so 4,3,1,7,38 etc etc ... its a dynamic array so it could be any number of numbers etc etc

What i need to do is extract each number and run it agains a function .. So for example each number represents a users id, i need to run each user id against a function and return a set result, so for each id i would neeed to run something like

```
$personsdetails = $this->random_model->get_user_details( $useridhere );
```

How would i go about getting each of the ids out of the array and running it over a loop to get each persons details?

Cheers

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use [explode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php) and [foreach](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php) over created array.

```
$userIds = explode(',', $yourstring);
foreach ($userIds as $userId) {
    $personsdetails = $this->random_model->get_user_details( $userId );
}
```

Comment: Is there any chance you could give me a bit of sample code? please

Comment: Ahhh this makes sense ... If theres only one number and no commas, will it return an error though?

Answer (score 0):

```
$var=explode(',',$database_value);
```

its comming in array

Answer (score 0):

$ids_raw = '1,2,3,4,5';

$ids = explode(',', $ids_raw);

foreach($ids as $id){

echo $id;
}

Answer (score 0):

Because you're bringing in a single dimension array, I'd suggest using a for() loop (personal preference).  The `explode()` function will split
 a string by the first argument you give it.  So in this case, explode is splitting the string in `$userIDs` by commas `','`.  Then we run each array element through your function.

```
$userIDs = '1,2,3';
$userIDs = explode(',',$userIDs);

for($x=0;$x<count($userIDs);$x++){
    $personsdetails = $this->random_model->get_user_details($userIDs[$x]);
};
```

Comment: Can you add some comments to clarify your answer so the OP and others can have a better understanding of it.

Comment: Added an explanation and tweaked the code.  Thanks for the suggestion.  I clearly need to fix my question answering process :-)